# Save Paragraphs as a PDF dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

Is it possible to use JSPDF to save paragraphs `<p>` that include borders as a PDF, incorporating the formatting and keeping the elements in the center of the page?

The following code allows paragraphs to be generated when text pasted into the `textarea`. As demonstrated within this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/) it seems that it is possible to save a table as a PDF.

---

However, is it possible to save the following dynamic paragraph and border as a PDF dynamically?

If an updated fiddle could be provided, it would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/2hcfbp2h/9/)

Thank You!

HTML:

```
 <div align="center"> 
     <h4 align="center">
         <u>Paste text in the field below to divide text into paragraphs.</u>
    </h4> 
    <textarea placeholder="Type text here, then press the button below." cols="50" id="textarea1" rows="10">
    </textarea>
    <br><br>
    <button id="Go">Divide Text into Paragraphs!</button> 
</div>
<hr> <h2 align="center">Dynamic Paragraphs will appear below: <br>[Paragraphs below for saving as PDF]</h2> <div> <div align="center" id="text_land" style="font-family: monospace"> </div></div>
```

JQuery:

```
   $(function(){$("#Go").on("click",function(){for(var t=$("textarea").val(),e=300;t.length;){for(;t.length>e&&" "!==t.charAt(e);)e++;$("#text_land").append("<br></br><p>"+t.substring(0,e)+"</p><br></br>"),t=t.substring(e),e=300,$("p").attr("contenteditable","true"),$("p").addClass("text")}})}),$("select").on("change",function(){var t=$("#text_land p"),e=this.dataset.property;t.css(e,this.value)}).prop("selectedIndex",0),end;
```

CSS:

```
@media print{p{page-break-inside:avoid}}p{position:relative}@media print{.no-print,.no-print *{display:none !important}}p{border-style:solid}p{color:#000}p{display:block;text-align:justify;border-width:5px;font-size:19px}p{overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:460px;word-wrap:break-word}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have edited your code. Please [see your sample here (edited)](https://jsfiddle.net/2hcfbp2h/18/)

I have used:

```
 background-color: white;
```

on "text_land"

Edit:

I examined [html2canvas.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js) It parses html element tree and draws according to their style.

Width of the top-most html element - "text_land" of the rendered tree was considered as a width of the resulting image. Everything, that went outside of the "text_land" div after page zoom, was not rendered.

The idea is to have separate styles for printing.

Comment: However, when resizing the window or zooming, the actual paragraph element changes size than the size specified when saving to PDF. Also, the PDF document is splitting the paragraph onto two separate pages, rather than allowing for the paragraph to move to the next page through margins. Therefore, is it possible to fix these issues?

Comment: @Dave Change `pagesplit: true` to `pagesplit: false` for no page break and as you have a fixed width on your `p` it doesn't matter what the window's width is. If you want `p` to follow the window, change `p`'s rule to percent like `width:80%;min-width:460px;`

Comment: Also, the text seems to be blurry when saving to PDF. Is this a problem that can be resolved, as it seems to be an issue from html2canvas.

Comment: About blurriness of the Generated PDF - Yes i have noticed that too.

There was another thing that i have noticed: When i set jspdf
A4 sheet dimensions in mm-millimeters, and then i create html div with same size in mm as i have set for jspdf, the div gets rendered much bigger then jspdf sheet size in both: width and height.
I think that this is connected with a pixel density of the users system: jspdf uses small pixel density. I assume that low pixel density of jspdf in comparison of user's pixel density should also be cause of blurriness of the resulting pdf. 

I need to look deeper.

Answer (score 3):

i did reworking on both of your fiddles and came up with something working, please to have a look at this fiddle

```
$(document).on('click','#Go',function(){                                
var value = $('#textarea1').val();


a=value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>');
$('#text_land p').html(a);
console.log(a);
});

$(document).on('click','#print',function(){


 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 pdf.addHTML($('#text_land')[0], function () {
 pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });

});
```

I have used html2canvas library.

Here's [a link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLhc4ty2/)!

---

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o24eaaz0/)!

---

[updated fiddle where resizing windows does not affect the oucome](http://jsfiddle.net/9xw4y7dg/)

Comment: However, the paragraph boxes, when generated as a PDF, seem to appear a different size compared to the fiddle. Also, the background color is no longer white like in the previous fiddle. Is it possible for these issues to be fixed as I have noticed the blurriness of the boxes when saved as a PDF is clearer compared to the previous fiddle?

Comment: When resizing the JSFiddle window, the PDF size of the paragraph tag changes and is not the original size. Is it possible to resolve these issues?

Comment: i have tried changing css a little bit, updating the answer mate